# Cannot access SQL Server MDF file through app, SQL Server Management Studio, or VS Server explorer

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am working on a C# Windows app using Entity Framework 6.

I have a database in a `.mdf` file that I created using SQL Server Management Studio.

The program will open and function fine several times. Eventually, seemingly randomly, it will not open anymore. This does not have to happen just through my app. Sometimes access will stop if going through VS server explorer only.

The app says **the login fails.**

SQL Server Management Studio says the **file is inaccessible or in use by another process**.

Also, I can move the file. This usually means there is no process using it. Why would sql think there is?

I have tried dozens of solutions found online. I have tried ending processes, ending tasks, restarting or stopping SQL Server services. I have tried many different connection string settings. NOTHING works until I restart my computer.

There are other databases on my computer that work fine. Can it be my code? Am I doing something that locks the file? Can it be the database? Is it corrupt?

Any and all help appreciated.

Connection string is:

```
string sConnectionString =
                @"metadata=res://*/DataModel.MoneyDataModel.csdl|
                           res://*/DataModel.MoneyDataModel.ssdl|
                           res://*/DataModel.MoneyDataModel.msl;
                    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                    provider connection string='
                        Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
                        Initial Catalog=" + Settings.Default.DataPath + @";
                        Integrated Security=True;
                        Timeout=True;
                        MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
                        App=EntityFramework;
                        User Instance = False;'";
```

UPDATE:

I think I found the problem.

It seems that trying to access a database with its MDF files in a Google Drive folder is causing the issue.

I moved the files and it seems to be working fine.

I see other answers now that confirm that you cannot keep MDF files on Google Drive.

Comment: Does it help if you close and reopen Visual Studio (important is that all Windows of Visual Studio are closed)?

Comment: No. I can close VS and SQL Management Studio.

I can even make sure I remove the connections to the database from both VS and Management Studio, then shut them down.

The file is still unable to be opened later.

Comment: Just be aware that an MDF file can also be 'attached' to a completely separate SQL Server installation. Here's a link containing a couple of methods to find out if anything has your file open at the time: https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that trying to access a database with its MDF files in a Google Drive folder is causing the issue.

I moved the files and it seems to be working fine.

I see other answers now that confirm that you cannot keep MDF files on Google Drive.